# Why is this javaclass getting this exception?

Tags: java, class

I got this code off of a website to adapt to use for something else, but when I tried it on Netbeans, it kept giving me issues. I looked through it and it looks solid but, I apparently not...
The exceptions are:

> "'{' Expected" and "class, interface, or enum expected."

I checked all of the brackets and braces and I can't figure out what's wrong with it.

```
public class Coin() 
{
    private String sideUp;

    /**
    * Default constructor
    */
    public Coin() 
    {
    // initialize sideUp
        toss();
    }

    /**
    * This method will simulate the tossing of a coin. It should set 
    * the   
    * sideUp field to either "heads" or "tails".
    */
    public void toss() 
    {

        Random rand = new Random();

        // Get a random value, 0 or 1.
        int value = rand.nextInt(2);

        if (value == 0) 
        {
            this.sideUp = "heads";
        } 
        else 
        {
        this.sideUp = "tails";
        }
    }

    /**
    * 
    * @return The side of the coin facing up.
    */
    public String getSideUp() 
    {
        return sideUp;
    }
}
```

Is there a brace I'm missing somewhere?

Comment: The program is also giving me a problem with the Rand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to **remove the parenthesis** from the class name, it should rather be:

```
public class Coin 
{
    ...
}
```

Only "*Java letters*" or "*Java digits*" are allowed in an identifier which don't include parenthesis cf [§3.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-Identifier) from the Java Language Specification.

Answer (score 0):

**Remove () from class name and do the required import.**

Workable code will be something like this :

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Coin {
    private String sideUp;

    /**
     * Default constructor
     */
    public Coin() {
        // initialize sideUp
        toss();
    }

    /**
     * This method will simulate the tossing of a coin. It should set the sideUp
     * field to either "heads" or "tails".
     */
    public void toss() {

        Random rand = new Random();

        // Get a random value, 0 or 1.
        int value = rand.nextInt(2);

        if (value == 0) {
            this.sideUp = "heads";
        } else {
            this.sideUp = "tails";
        }
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return The side of the coin facing up.
     */
    public String getSideUp() {
        return sideUp;
    }
}
```